# JAX-WS Handler operation name

Tags: web-services, websphere, jax-ws, apache-axis, websphere-8

I'm running JAX-WS services on WebSphere 8.5.5.8 with Axis2 1.5.4 runtime.

Is there any good method, how to get operation name from context in the hander? I cannot extract it from XML Envelope, because there's different names in body for response and request.

OperationName is unfortunatelly null and the real operation name is in nested messageCtx which is inacessible.

Answer (score 0):

Please try SOAPMessageContext.WSDL_OPERATION

Comment: That's the null I was talking about, this unfortunately don't work.